# Shell32.dll .NET interface is dependent from the OS

Tags: .net, interop, shell32

I want to find every application listed in the user program menu. I use the following routine:

```
private static void ProcessDirectoryLnkFiles(string path, bool recurse,
    UpdateProcessFromLnkDelegate sProcFile)
{
    try 
    {
        string[] sPrograms = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk",
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        string[] sSubdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();

        foreach (string p in sPrograms) {
            Shell32.Folder sLinkFolder;
            Shell32.FolderItem sLinkFolderItem;
            Shell32.ShellLinkObject sLinkObject;
            string sLinkFullpath;

            // Get link full path
            sLinkFullpath = Path.GetFullPath(p);
            // Get link folder
            sLinkFolder = shell.NameSpace(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(sLinkFullpath));
            // Get link item
            sLinkFolderItem = sLinkFolder.Items().
                Item(Path.GetFileName(sLinkFullpath));
            // Get link object
            sLinkObject = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)
                sLinkFolderItem.GetLink;

            if (sLinkObject.Target.IsFolder == false)
                sProcFile(sLinkObject);
        }

        if (recurse == true)
            foreach (string dir in sSubdirs) 
                ProcessDirectoryLnkFiles(dir, true, sProcFile);
    } 
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException eUnauthorizedAccessException) {
        sLog.Warn("Unable to iterate on directory {0} ({1}).", 
            path, eUnauthorizedAccessException.Message); 
    } 
    catch (IOException eIOException) {
        sLog.Warn("Unable to iterate on directory {0} ({1}).", 
            path, eIOException.Message);
    } 
    catch (COMException eCOMException) {                
    } 
    catch {
        throw;
    }
 }
```

This runs quite well on Windows 7 x64.  But unfortunately, on Windows XP x86 the `Shell32.Shell` object doesn't declare the `Shell32.Shell.Target` property. How do I make this code run on Windows XP?

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/VBNET/388996/388996/using-shell32-on-different-operating-systems/ ?

Comment: You don't need `catch { throw; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Path property, that gives you the path to the target.  System.IO.Directory.Exists() can then tell you if it is directory or not.

Comment: It would be nice if there were an ability to get this kind of information avoiding the use of Shell32 alltogether.